# In PHP how to output the contents of a radiobox array using POST?

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I want to output the values of the checkbox in the same way I'm outputting the values from the text fields. Since the checkbox can have multiple inputs I'm using an array for that but trying to cycle through the array for values hasn't worked for me. 
tried foreach($type as $item) and echoing $item within the HTML like it says in the PHP book I have but that hasn't worked. 
How should I do and where should the code be? I'm also unable to use PHP within the HTML for some reason, I'm not sure why that is or if its something to do with the echo<<<_END or not. Help appreciated.

```
<?php // formtest.php
if (isset($_POST['game'])) $game = $_POST['game'];
else $game = "(Not entered)";
if (isset($_POST['genre'])) $genre = $_POST['genre'];
else $genre = "(Not entered)";
if (isset($_POST['type'])) $type = $_POST['type'];
else $type = "(Not entered)";
echo <<<_END
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Test</title>
</head>
<body>
Your game is: $game in the $genre genre and of the type<br />
<form method="post" action="formtest.php">
    What is your game?
    <input type="text" name="game" />
    <br />
    What is your genre?
    <input type="text" name="genre" />
    <br />
    Type?
       Retail <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Retail" />
Downloadable <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Downloadable" />
Free <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Free" />
<br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
_END;
```

?>

Comment: don't wrap You html in heredoc. just close (?>) php and add variables to Your html like this: ?>(closed php)  <html><head><title><?=$title?></title></head>

Comment: @JurisMalinens That can be a nightmare to watch and develop in files that require a lot of variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the form as it is now, `$_POST['type']` will be an array since it's using checkboxes (and named appropriately), not radios.  Here I just implode it for display, but you can loop through it like any array.  It should be worth noting that any time you're wondering what a form is giving you, you can `var_dump($_POST)` or `var_dump($_GET)` depending on where the data is coming from.  It helps a lot with debugging.

Here's what I got, I switched from heredoc, but your heredoc should work fine if you add `$type` back in somewhere, I didn't notice it in the original code:

```
<?php // formtest.php
if (isset($_POST['game'])) $game = $_POST['game'];
else $game = "(Not entered)";
if (isset($_POST['genre'])) $genre = $_POST['genre']; //Edit: Fixed line, oops
else $genre = "(Not entered)";
if (isset($_POST['type'])) $type = implode(', ',$_POST['type']);
else $type = "(Not entered)";

//Normally I'd specify a charset, but for simplicity's sake I won't here.
$type = htmlspecialchars($type);
$game = htmlspecialchars($game);
$genre = htmlspecialchars($genre);

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Test</title>
</head>
<body>
Your game is: <?php echo $game; ?> in 
the <?php echo $genre; ?> genre and of the type <?php echo $type; ?><br />
<form method="post" action="">
    What is your game?
    <input type="text" name="game" />
    <br />
    What is your genre?
    <input type="text" name="genre" />
    <br />
    Type?
       Retail <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Retail" />
Downloadable <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Downloadable" />
Free <input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="Free" />
<br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Addendum:
If you switched and used radios like

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="Downloadable" />
```

`$_POST['type']` would be a simple string since you can only select one of the set.

Comment: Thanks this is great, I made a mistake in the question title merging checkboxs and radio buttons together, I did mean checkboxes as in your code.

Comment: Ah, cool, glad to here it.  If you ever need to do stuff with the input, the array functions PHP provides are really handy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first you don't need to echo the entire html output.  Second your questions says radio buttons, but the html shows checkboxes.  A radio field will only produce one result so you don't need [] after then name.  Checkboxes will return an array when named with a [].  So if you are using checkboxes you will need to process the result as an array.  If you change the field to radio it should work fine.

```
<?php // formtest.php
if (isset($_POST['game'])) {
    $game = $_POST['game'];
}
else { $game = "(Not entered)"; }
if (isset($_POST['genre'])) {
    $genre = $_POST['genre'];
}
else { $genre = "(Not entered)"; }
if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
    $type = $_POST['type'];
}
else { $type = "(Not entered)"; }
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Form Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Your game is: <?php echo $game; ?> in the <?php echo $genre; ?> genre and of the type <?php echo $type; ?><br />
    <form method="post" action="test.php">
      What is your game?
      <input type="text" name="game" <?php if ($game != "(Not entered)") { echo "value='" . $game . "'"; } ?> />
      <br />
      What is your genre?
      <input type="text" name="genre" <?php if ($genre != "(Not entered)") { echo "value='" . $genre . "'"; } ?> />
      <br />
      Type?
      Retail <input type="radio" name="type" value="Retail" <?php if ($type == "Retail") { echo "checked"; } ?> />
      Downloadable <input type="radio" name="type" value="Downloadable" <?php if ($type == "Downloadable") { echo "checked"; } ?> />
      Free <input type="radio" name="type" value="Free" <?php if ($type == "Free") { echo "checked"; } ?> />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To the file you post it the type[] will be saved as an array. For example

$a=$_POST['type'];

Although I don't find any point in doing this to radio-buttons, because their purpose is to pass only 1 value(unless you want specifically to).